# Infopath to Sharepoint: Create multiple list items from a date range?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-server

I have a request from a client to create a SharePoint/InfoPath form that has Start Date and End Date fields.  Their request is that when submitted it will make a separate entry for each day in the date range.  For example:  John Doe is out from 4/1 - 4/3.  When submitted it will make an entry that he was out 4/1, 4/2, and 4/3.  this is requested due to them wanting to have a SharePoint list that shows all the day and not use a calendar.

This question was previously posted on another forum by another individual a year ago with no responses so I'm hoping for better results than he got lol.

Any ideas or pointing me in the right direction in terms of how to begin this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance and I hope everyone is having a great day!

Comment: Where do you have to store each entry? Can it be a separate list? and what version of SP?

Comment: Preferably it would be in the same list and their using SharePoint 2010 with the latest SP/CU.  There idea is to have a form (SharePoint or InfoPath) with a People Picker for a field, a Start Date field, a End Date Field.  Once submitted it makes a list entry for each day between start date and end date for that day.  Their intent is to use it like a PTO Log but don't want to enter a new entry each time if a person is out for the entire week (5 days).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an event receiver subscribing the itemAdded event, then iterate over the start date until the end date and create new entries in the list.

Just remember to disable further events firing within the method using EventFiringEnabled = false

Answer (score 0):

I would create an ASP.NET WCF Service which uses Client Object Model to interact with SharePoint.. And call this service from InfoPath form and pass the parameters to one of the functions which will be responsible for adding items in the list..

You can simply use C# and iterate through the start till end date and make entries in the list..